# Экранирование символов в запросе curl

Tags: php, curl

Добрый вечер, у меня проблема с `POST` запросом на `CURL`.

`CURL` запрос мне возвращает ответ:

> Failed to connect to ipaytest.arca.am port 8445: Connection refused

Но тот же самый запрос если я делаю просто в браузере как `GET` запрос то мне возвращает желаемый ответ. Можете сказать что я делаю не так?

У меня сомнения на то что пароль в моем запросе не принимается сервером, потому что в нем содержаться специальные символы. Может такое быть?

Вот мой `CURL` код на `PHP`:

```
$args = array(
    'userName' => 'test',
    'password' => 'test',
    'orderNumber' => '16_5',
    'amount' => 1000,
    'returnUrl' => SHOP_URL . '?wc-api=wc_acbapayment&acbapayment=result&order_id=' . $order_id . $extra_url_param,
);
$acbacurl = curl_init();
if ($acbacurl) {$this->acba_logger('276curl-yes');}else{$this->acba_logger('276curl-no');};
$c=curl_setopt_array($acbacurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $action_adr,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($args)
));
if( ! $response = curl_exec($acbacurl))
{
    $this->acba_logger('285curl_error:'.curl_error($acbacurl));exit('Error '.curl_error($acbacurl));
}
//$response = curl_exec($acbacurl);
curl_close($acbacurl);

$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

А вот тот же самый запрос на `GET` который работает нормально:

```
https://ipaytest.arca.am:8445/payment/rest/register.do?userName=test&password=test&orderNumber=16_12&amount=1000&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.studentstesting.com%2F%3Fwc-api%3Dwc_acbapayment%26acbapayment%3Dresult%26order_id%3D16%26wc-callb%3Dcallback_function
```

Comment: Просто на этой страниц обрабатывается только GET запрос видимо..Есть ли какая нибудь API для  `ipaytest.arca.am` ?

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Нет если меняю `POST` запрос на `GET` та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Я понял ,по тому это из за вида POST параметров.Попробуй  1) `json_encode($args)`,2) http_build_query($args, '', '&'),.В принципе в документации должно быть написано в каком виде он ожидает эти параметры

Comment: Или можно` urlencode` значения в массиве `$args = array_filter($args,function($val){
    return urlencode($val);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если через браузер проходит,а браузер кодирует GET параметры,то и вам строит их кодировать при `POST` запросе.Смотреть **[urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)** функцию.

Для начала все это можно потестить элементарно,создав HTML форму и заполнить инпутами.

```
<form class="arca__form" action="https://ipaytest.arca.am:8445/payment/rest/register.do" method="post">
    <?php
        foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
            echo "<input type='text' nmae='{$key}' value='".urlencode($value)."' />";
        }
    ?>
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Сделать Ajax запрос:

```
<script>
    $('.arca__form').on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDfault();

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            mthod: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serializeArray(),
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

И если получится то либо продолжать в этом духе,либо все это эмулировать через CURL.Тут я намекаю на посылаемые заголовки которые отправляются при `form submit`.

Comment: Ну раз используете аякс, то и вовсе `action` можно выкинуть и забыть про него, как страшный сон.

Comment: ajax в данном случае редко отработает - так как `ipaytest.arca.am:8445` может не давать CORS заголовки кому попало, это раз. Даже если форму отправлять просто, не через `ajax` а простым сабмитом: на данном хосте может стоять простенькая защита от CSRF - с проверкой реферера, и блокированием чужих запросов. Так что это сомнительный способ проверить работоспособность запроса :)

Comment: @And нет, нельзя. Автор ответа убивает двух зайцев сразу - во первых код репрезентативен, и при взгляде на форму понятно, куда  как и что она отправляет. Во вторых при убийстве скрипта - форма в каком-то виде продолжит работать: это гибкость.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, Это было как примечание, что если направлено на `Ajax` - то и использовать нужно `Ajax`, а не `Submit` и `Ajax` вместе., ибо смысла так-таковы нет, потому что - все равно происходит предотвращение события `Submit`, хотя с другой стороны, лучше тогда сделать `<form ... onsubmit="return form(this)"> ...` - а функцией возвращать `return false`.

Comment: @And так неправильное примечание. Автор и использует исключительно ajax - если вы не заметили - там `e.preventDfault()` , почему так лучше - я уже сказал выше

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, а зачем убивать скрипт? Это не нормально. И карается.

Comment: @And затем, что в большом коде - когда скриптов на 5 метров: может произойти ошибка, которая прервёт весь поток выполнения, так устойчивее. Но главное не это - главное соблюдение первого правила программирования: смотрю на код, сразу понимаю что делает.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, Если там синтаксическая ошибка, то это проблемы программиста, который не умеет отлаживать код, а остальное нужно перехватывать и не давать программе рухнуть.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to connect to ipaytest.arca.am port 8445: Connection refused

Мы негодавали почему поличили такую ошибку, потом оказалось что наш хостинг провайдер блокирует запросы на порт 8445.

Соответственно мы написали им и они добавили исходящие подключения к порту 8445 в белый список для нашей учетной записи.